# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Webapi Project returns Origin as null in header

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, cross-domain

I have a WebApi project to provide data and a ASP.NET Core 3.1 project to call the APIs.
I used Api caller Header fields like HOST, REFERER and ORIGIN to detect the client domain name which called Api to provide proper data, don't want to post/get domain as the parameter from client, just want to other domains call my api and I provide data based on the domain name, I implemented like:

```
        Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Host", out var traceValueHost);
        Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Referer", out var traceValueReferer);
        Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Origin", out var traceValueOrigin);
```

But when I publish the code all 3 returns null. Actually I cannot detect the client domain and face errors, what would be the problem? How clients have to get/post to send me their domain names in their Webapi call headers?

Comment: Are you actually setting those headers in the request? Please show how.

Comment: @Xerillio I don't , I expected those headers to be available, Now I added the domain name to header as Origin and it worked, but what if the client sourse was not mine, how I can detect the WebApi consumer domain name?

Comment: The only way you can really trust that someone is who they say they are is to require them to authenticate against your API. Such as certificate security, API keys etc. As you can see, anyone can put anything they want in the HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found was adding Origin to the client domain headers

```
    public static async Task<T> GetWebApiAsync<T>(string postUrl, string domain="")
    {
        HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        if (domain != "")
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Origin", domain);

        string result = await Client.GetAsync(postUrl)?
            .Result?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync()??string.Empty;

        if (result == string.Empty) return default(T);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
    }
```